# Qt: How to resize a window to its new content

Tags: qt

I have a window containing a `QScrollArea` with a couple widgets in it.

Until now, I was creating the `QScrollArea` and its child widgets in the constructor of my window, and then I was resizing the window vertically to fit its content using `resize(400, sizeHint().height())`.  So far, so good.

Now, I'm adding or removing widgets in the `QScrollArea` at runtime.  What should I do, after having added or removed widgets, to make the window fits its content vertically?  Should I call `adjustSize()`?  `resize(sizeHint())`?  Should there be a call to `layout->activate()` or maybe `updateGeometry()` first?  Which size policies actually matter in this case?  The ones of the window, or of the scroll area, or both?  I tried to set them all to `Expanding`.

I'm using Qt 4.6 on Windows.

Comment: Do you want the QScrollArea to not have scrollbars?

Comment: Absolutely, right now the idea is to get rid of the vertical scrollbar. The next step will be to allow it to appear only if the total height of the QScrollArea content is really too big, or if the user resizes the window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that calling `resize(sizeHint())` (without any other magic) after widgets were added to the scroll area actually does the trick.  Somehow missed that the first time.

Comment: I needed it for vertical adjustment, and this came out: `QSize s = sizeHint(); s.setWidth(width()); resize(s);`

Comment: Maybe this will help somebody else that finds this question but has my problem instead.  The dialog actually was resizing for the content, but because of the size of the window in QT designer it was getting chopped off at the bottom.  Resizing the window in QT designer to allow for more room at the bottom fixed it for me

Comment: This solution will probably only work on Windows. An alternative solution is given in this Qt Forum thread: [Resize top level window to fit contents](https://forum.qt.io/post/80850).